# How to create protected routes with react-app-link toRoute({render})

Tags: node.js, react-router-v4

I'm refactoring code to be DRY by using react-app-link to handle routes. 
Most of my routes are protected and I am having trouble protecting my routes when using MyLocation.toRoute().

I have successfully generated unprotected routes. 
But when trying to protect the route I get a lot of cryptic error messages. 
Unfortunately the ract-app-link documentation is not extensive on the render option.

```
//Link object
const wholeNbr = Yup.number().integer().positive()
const MyLocation = new Location('/doc/:id', {id : wholeNbr.required()})

//Unprotected route - Working code:
{ MyLocation.toRoute({ component: MyComponent, invalid: NotFoundPage }, true) }

//Protected route - Not working:
const privateLocation = (isAuthenticated, Component) => (
  isAuthenticated ? 
  (
    <Component />
  ):(
    <Redirect to="/" /> //redirect to login page
  )
)
...
<Router history={history}>
  ...
  <Switch>
  ...
  { CategoryLocation.toRoute({ render: privateLocation(isAuthenticated, MyComponent), invalid: NotFoundPage }, true) }
  ...
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

I expect the component to render, but receive the error "TypeError: _render is not a function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! I was not passing a function to the render prop. 
The code should read:

```
{ CategoryLocation.toRoute({ render: () => privateLocation(isAuthenticated, MyComponent), invalid: NotFoundPage }, true) }
```